# Building a Listener in Salesforce (using Apex)

Tags: apex, community, soap-api, wsdl2apex

I have build an outbound message workflow in ORG A, and I want to test this end to end with my other ORGB -by building a listener in ORGB.

I can code,only in Apex language . I have imported the WSDL from ORG A to ORG B.

and now am not sure how to test and what tool to use? Please guide .

P.S: I tried using http://requestb.in/ ,but the outbound message keeps failing with delivery failure status = org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog. so i want to use a tool and see whats wrong in this.

Comment: What endpoint are you sending it to? Seems to me you could create a rest method is org B to receive and parse the XML.

Comment: right now am sending it to the url i created using requestb.in, i am not aware how to do this via Soap / IDE...Any reference would  help? Also, my ORGA and ORGB  sandboxes share the same CS* server,so am not sure how would my workflow endpoint distinguish the URL to know that it has to connect to ORGB

Comment: So the error you are getting is from Requestb.in?

Comment: yes it is from Requestb.in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outbound Messaging expects a well formed SOAP response, otherwise it claims the message failed and will try again later. That is likely the issue you get with anything like requestb.in

Take a look at this blog for some guidance:
http://www.tgerm.com/2014/08/testing-soap-outbound-messages-without-failures-saxexception.html